# Very basic show/hide div with radio buttons in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have two radio buttons (#bill and #invoice). When I click the radiobutton #invoice, I want a div to show up (#periods). When I click on #bill, I want #periods to hide. When I click back on #invoice, I want it to show up again.

I have tried everything (.prop, :checked, length === etc). Can anybody help me with this very basic problem?

```
if ($("#invoice:checked").length == 1) {
        $('#periods').hide();
        $('#periods').show();

    } 
    else if ($("#bill:checked").length == 1) {
        $('#periods').hide();
    }
    else {
            $('#periods').hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: if($(element).is(':checked')){} ... it worked?

Comment: Can i post the correct answer?

Comment: @Roy yes thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to check if a input:check is checked.

```
if($(element).is(':checked')){ /* IS CHECKED */}
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can place a common class on both radios. You can then hook a `change` event handler to them, and show the `#periods` div based on the value of the chosen radio. Try this:

```js
$('.radio').change(function(){
  $('#periods').toggle(this.value == 'bill');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="type" value="bill" class="radio" checked />Bill<br />
<input type="radio" name="type" value="invoice" class="radio" />Invoice<br /><br />

<div id="periods">
  #PERIODS
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the most compact way to write this is as below:

```
$("#periods").toggle($("#invoice").prop("checked"))
```

This works if invoice and bill alternate, which from my understanding is the case.